# Передавать в метод поле класса

Tags: c#, list, методы

По мере получения данных, изменяю значение полей у элементов класса(List<'User1>).Возможно ли сделать метод, в который можно было бы передать какое именно поле необходимо изменять? Часть кода, в котором необходимо менять поле.

```
for (int i = 0; i < first.Count; i++)
            {
                foreach (var v in Test)
                {
                    v.Name(<--это) += result[i] + " ";
                    i++;
                }
                Array.Clear(result, 0, 19);
            }
```

*Отдельно выше метода лежат GetValue и SetValue*

Вот код метода в общем:

```
void fills(List<string> first, List<User1> Test, string fieldN)
        {
            string[] result = new string[20];
            for (int i = 0; i < first.Count; i++)
            {
                foreach (var v in first)
                {
                    result[i] += v + " ";
                    i++;
                }
            }
            //for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
            //{
            //    testbox.Text += result[i] + " ";
            //}
                for (int i = 0; i < first.Count; i++)
                {
                    foreach (var v in Test)
                    {
                    SetValue(v, fieldN, Convert.ToString(GetValue(v, fieldN)) + result[i] + " ");
                    i++;
                    }
                    Array.Clear(result, 0, 19);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Вам надо пройтись по листу и у каждого  его элемента изменить конкретное поле?

Comment: Да.Причем в метод передавать наименование поля.Ну чтобы не создавать десять методов для каждого поля, а просто в один метод передавать поле, которое необходимо изменить

Comment: передавайте в метод Action или воспользуйтесь Linq

Comment: что то типа `data.ForEach(item => item.Name += "OOO");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private object GetValue(object aParent, string aFieldName)
{
  FieldInfo field = aParent.GetType().GetField(aFieldName);
  if (field != null)
    return field.GetValue(aParent);

  PropertyInfo prop = aParent.GetType().GetProperty(aFieldName);
  if (prop != null)
    return prop.GetValue(aParent);

  return null;
}

private void SetValue(object aParent, string aFieldName, object aValue)
{
  FieldInfo field = aParent.GetType().GetField(aFieldName);
  if (field != null)
    field.SetValue(aParent, aValue);

  PropertyInfo prop = aParent.GetType().GetProperty(aFieldName);
  if (prop != null)
    prop.SetValue(aParent, aValue);
}


SetValue(v, "Name", Convert.ToString(GetValue(v, "Name")) + result[i] + " ");
```

Comment: GetValue вылетает с ошибкой: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.".Объекты создаются до вызова метода-затем, вызываю метод.Экземпляры есть, но часть полей пустые, т.к. ничего не присваивал им.SetValue засунул в цикл foreach, поменяв "Name", на передаваемую строку fieldN.Может я сделал что-то не так?

Comment: @Ricarnev Добавьте новый код в вопрос.

Comment: Вопрос обновил: привёл весь метод.

Comment: Извините, но разве может быть в void слово return? (SetValue) Студия ругается.

Comment: Всё, работает, благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, вам подойдёт следующий подход:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<Person> people = new List<Person> {
            new Person { Age = 20, Name = "Smit" },
            new Person { Age = 30, Name = "John" } };

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Print();
            Do(p => p.Name += "!");
            Print();
            Do(p => p.Age += 1);
            Print();
        }

        static void Do(Action<Person> act)
        {
            foreach (var p in people)
                act(p);
        }

        static void Print()
        {
            foreach (var p in people)
                Console.WriteLine(p.Age + " " + p.Name);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    class Person
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Метод `Do` принимает `Action<Person>`. При его вызове можно указать конкретное свойство, причём всё будет строго типизировано.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, ваш способ также попробую.Просто необходимо немного подстроить под свой код) У меня List не статический, поэтому позже попробую и отпишусь о результате