# Запись в поля по имени

Tags: c#

Всем привет!

Пишу клиент для связи с устройством по протоколу МЭК 60870-5-104. На самом деле что за протокол не суть важно.

В результате опроса сервера клиентом я получаю посылку, в которой есть адрес и есть значение. Есть таблица адресов, в которой адрес указывает на то, значение какого параметра(ток, напряжение, битовая индикация) скрывается под этим адресом.

Создаю класс, описывающий измерительное устройство. Полями являются измеряемые величины и битовые индикаторы. При получении посылки я извлекаю из нее адрес и по этому самому адресу могу, посмотрев в таблицу, определить что за величина получена.

Вопрос в следующем - как лучше заполнять поля класса при получении посылки?
У меня не установлена связь между полем и адресом в программе, то есть я явно должен прописать на данный момент, если Package.Address == 1, то Device.Voltage = Package.Value, к примеру, а таких полей может быть много.

Самый прямолинейный вариант делать через switch-case указанным выше образом.

Думал создать перечисление, в котором указать переменные, имена которых идентичны именам полей класса и им присвоить адреса из таблицы. Таким образом, приходит посылка -> смотрим адрес в перечислении -> получаем из перечисления имя переменной -> по имени переменной определяем в какое поле пишем значение -> пишем значение в поле (по имени как-то???)

Comment: нуу, создай класс назови поля так чтоб было понятно что ето за поля.
 потом создай обьект( екземпляр класса) и заполняй его поля.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/847471/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0/847476#847476

Comment: А зачем вам вообще в этой ситуации класс для параметров? Не пойдёт ли просто Dictionary?

Comment: @VladD А поля в классе различных типов. Dictionary, так понимаю, не подходит.

Comment: @Oleg92: И правда, ну тогда лучше, чем switch, вряд ли что-то придумается.